# Struggling with RegionFunction

Tags: plotting

When I try to use a pre-defined expression in RegionFunction, I get errors:

```
f = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1
g = x+y+z
ContourPlot3D[f == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= g]]
```

I've tried to fix this with using eg "With", but I haven't been able to. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `ContourPlot3D` like other plotting functions has the attribute `HoldAll` so, as pointed out by @cvgmt, must be evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Evaluate`.

```
f = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1;
g = x + y + z;
ContourPlot3D[f == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -2, 5}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= g // Evaluate], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None]
```